# jQuery + Sortable + live

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm adding list items to a page dynamically with $.get, then appending them to the OL element. Pretty usual to this point.

But jQuery isn't aware of these new items when they get loaded into the page, and I'm not being able to make them sortable.

I made some trials with jQuery Live, but didn't get anywhere whit that...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `refresh` method of `.sortable()` does not seem to recognize `li`'s which are NOT added via the `.sortable()` functions.

Try adding your `.sortable()` initialisation code into a function which you call on document ready AND in you code where you dynamically add `li`'s.

Instead of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mySortableOL").sortable({
        ...
    });
}
...
jQuery("#mySortableOL").append(...);
jQuery("#mySortableOL").sortable("refresh");
```

Try something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mySortableOL").doSort();
}
...
jQuery("#mySortableOL").append(...);
doSort();
...
function doSort(){
    jQuery("#mySortableOL").sortable({
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: It is not only the LI, it is basically everything, but the approach is correct and working.

Comment: Exactly a correct answer. Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 7):

Did you try .sortable('refresh')?
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-refresh

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? This is by the far the cleanest way of managing this ajax issue.

Answer (score 0):

on the tail end of your code just append `.sortable({});` with all your parameters respecified.  There's probably a way to do this without duplicating your code by using a function or something, but at least this works.

```
$('#List').live('click',function(e){

var myHTMLcode = '<li>New Item</li>'

myHTMLcode.appendTo('#List').sortable({
 items  : 'li',
 axis  : 'xy',    

 update  : function(event, ui){SPECIFIC Sortable FUNCTION CODE HERE}).fadeIn();
)};
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this solution and working fine for me.

```
makesortable = function(){
        $( "#mylist" ).sortable({
            ...
        })
      };
...
// after list refresh :
makesortable();
```