# Unable to select id attribute from ajax returned page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I want to implement a page with 2 lists, and it allows user to drag and drop items between the two lists. This can be implement by using jQuery UI library:

**html:**

```
<!--list A-->
<div id='list_a'>
  <ul class='sortable'></ul>
</div>

<!--list B-->
<div id='list_b'>
  <ul class='sortable'>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***js：***

```
$( "ul.sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    dropOnEmpty: true
});

$( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

The problem is, when I using jQuery ajax to generate `list B`, the drag and drop does not work anymore. I suspect that the jQuery is unable to select the `ul .sortable`, because when  I view the HTML source, I can only see `<div id='list_b'></div>`.

**My ajax code:**

```
$('#field_a h3 a').click(function() {
    var form_data = {
        required_data:$(this).text().trim(),
        ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_list_b',
        dataType: 'html',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(msg){
            $('#list_b').html(msg);
        }
   });
});
```

I am using CodeIgniter. Any idea?

Comment: I believe this other SO question is basically the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672182/jquery-sortable-live

Comment: Please note that the "view source" never shows the tags that are created by JS or JQ. It only shows the HTML received from the web server.

Comment: @summerbulb: No wonder I can not see the code from "view source", thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the first:**

what is the element $('#field_a h3 a') ?

**second:**

it doesn't work because when you do that $('#list_b').html(msg) - you are removing the UL element.

So, your binds referencing to the unexisting element.

you can do like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'get_list_b',
        dataType: 'html',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(msg){
            var list=$('#list_b');
            list.html(msg);
            $( "ul.sortable",list ).sortable({
                connectWith: "ul",
                dropOnEmpty: true
            });
        }
   });
```

and it could be more helpful if you could put your example to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `$('#field_a h3 a')` is just a h3 with a link, which can trigger the call to load the list b. Thank you for your explanation, it's working now :)